# How do I calculate the runing time of the following algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

> Question : Analyse the ruunnig time of  the following algorithm ?
>   T(n)=Cop * C(n)

```
flag=false;
count=0;
for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
{
    if (A[i]==1)
        count++;
    flag=true;
}
else
    flag=false;
return(count);
```

> What is the total time?
>   Suppose n = 50 .

Comment: I'm quite sure this isn't the actual implementation; the `else` seems to complement a `for` loop, which hardly makes sense; is this supposed to be C or C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *format out* the code, you'll find out that it *doesn't compile*. You, probably, mean something like this (please, notice, that assigning `flag` within the loop is of *no use*: you have to check the *last item only*)

```
flag = false;
count = 0;

for(i = 0; i <= n; i++) 
  if (A[i] == 1) {
    count++;

    flag = true;
  }
  else
    flag = false;

return(count);
```

A better implementation:

```
count = 0;

for(i = 0; i <= n; i++) 
  if (A[i] == 1) 
    count += 1;

flag = (n >= 0) && (A[n] == 1);
```

So far so good, if `A` is large enough (`A.Length > n`) you have `O(n)` time complexity, so the execution time can be approximated by *linear function*:

```
t = k * n + b
```

where `k` and `b` are constants (specific to the workstation, compiler, OS etc.) which can be derived from the experiments.

Answer (score 1):

In the current form, the runtime complexity of the algorithm (which is what the question is apparently about) would be

```
O(n)
```

where `n` is the number of elements in `A` which are to be processed.

Comment: Unless A[0] is always 1.. :-)

Comment: @user1429080 No, if `A[0]` is 1, the loop still does `n` iterations.

Comment: Heh, you are correct. I somehow thought it breaks when the flag is set, despite what the code in front of my eyes said. Anyway, I of course agree with your answer...